# I'm getting a 404 page not found except home page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created my website using kohana framework and hosted in godaddy. I'm getting 404 page not found error in all links except home page. I have attached .htaccess file here. Kindly provide any ideas regarding this isuse.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
#RewriteBase /kohana/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
# RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Where is the .haccess located?

Comment: Am using godaddy . This is the path where i have placed my .htaccess file  " httpdocs / scanan_crm ". scanan_crm folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that .htaccess is in the same directory as all .php files are. /public_html/ or a folder like this.

**Working Example**

```
RewriteEngine On

//Optional: Redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

//Optional: Redirect http:// to https://
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

//Edit the URL (Without parameter)
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php [QSA]

//Edit the URL (With parameter)
RewriteRule ^user/edit/([0-9]*)/?$ user_edit.php?user_id=$1 [QSA]
```

If you are hosting on GoDaddy you usually don't need to make a .htaccess for the index.php file.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your idea. Am using Godaddy hosting,  i have placed my application with .htaccess file in one folder. I tried your answer, but not worked. can u give me any other solution ?

Comment: Do you have cPanel from GoDaddy? If yes maybe there is another problem.

Comment: I don't have cpanel, am using shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It happend to me once, i don´t know if it will be the same problem for you but i know that some hosting servers work using case sensitive urls

Example:
if your file has this name= "Login.php"
and if you try to acces to it like this= "login.php" it will not work and that is also applied to the name of folders.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got a question mark in your last line that doesn't belong there, it should be:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L]`

Or else try:

`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]`